# Identifying which JSP files are running

Tags: java, debugging, jsp, servlets

I work on  a huge jsp/servlet project and it has a templating system and it is fairly complex (hard to point which jsp files are imported because it is based on chosen template and some other parameters).When I test the site with web browser  I want to identify which jsp file is running without adding debug information to lots of jsp files. How could I do that? Any trick?
By the way I use eclipse and tomcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [`Filter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) which is mapped as follows

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>yourFilterName</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

and does roughly the following job in the `doFilter()` method.

```
String requestURI = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
String forwardURI = (String) request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);
String includeURI = (String) request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.INCLUDE_REQUEST_URI);

if (includeURI != null) {
    System.out.println("JSP included: " + includeURI);
} else if (forwardURI != null) {
    System.out.println("JSP forwarded: " + requestURI); // No, not forwardURI!
} else {
    System.out.println("JSP requested: " + requestURI);
}

chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although servlet-api.2.4.jar is on my lib RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI and RequestDispatcher.INCLUDE_REQUEST_URI can not be resolved. I already imported javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher.

Comment: You're welcome. Servletcontainer specific libs doesn't belong in `/WEB-INF/lib`. Project, targeted runtime and web.xml must be set to at least a Servlet 2.3 compatible one (that's when `Filter` was introduced). Preferably set it to the highest as the targeted runtime supports. An alternative is to hardcode those values. See the constant field values in the Javadoc.

Comment: Thanks again.I resolved the problem. These static constants comes with Servlet 3.0 spesification. At least Tomcat 7 required.